# Advanced stylization of jqplot line

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I'm trying to implement some advanced stylization of my jqplot linegraph.  I'm trying to make it resemble a heart monitor.

In order to do so, I need to fully customize the shadow to give ti that "glow" effect... but customizing the shadow any further than what the .js file allows you to is difficult.

Even more difficult - is there any way to "pulse" the line?  Preferably, at a given interval to send either a pulse through the line or just flash it's color/shadow or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick thought, but what if you plotted a base line (in the shape of the "heart" pulse) and then plotted a second line on top of it with the "glow" effect (I'm thinking a white/silver line that's 70% transparent).  You could then animate the "glow" line over and over.

Use the built in animation, and a setTimeout, at the same speed to call replot over and over.

Comment: You are welcome.  If you get something working I would love to see it.  It's an interesting question and I wanted to work out an example program but I just don't have the time.